# Can't use Instagram API to comment in my iOS app

Tags: ios, comments, instagram

I always get this message "Please visit http://bit.ly/instacomments for commenting access" when I use the endpoint /media/media-id/comments (see http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/) to post a comment to a friend's post in my iOS app, I requested these scopes from Instagram: scope=likes+comments+relationships.

I visited the web page mentioned in the error message and filled the form, months ago and not only once, but no lucky.

I also sent email to apidevelopers[at]instagram.com for access, still no lucky, and no response.

Anybody knows what w should I do?

Comment: I've had the same issues as @Fuli above. Been using their contact form and sending emails and getting no response at all. Are there any alternative means of communicating with the team? Do they read this board?

Comment: Same here. I filled their form weeks ago and still haven't received any update. I don't know how to reach them either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a request to Instagram to get access to posting comments through the API. The email address is in the developer documentation. If you follow the link you are receiving in the error, it will take you to the page to request access.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Rollins! I have sent email to apidevelopers[at]instagram.com (the email is from the API document) months ago for multiple times, I also went to http://bit.ly/instacomments and filled the form to request access, but nothing happened, I have waited for months, I included app name, client ID and app description in the email. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: OMG, I cant believe so many people have this, Why they dont response. We need to build something up.